# Using finish() method in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, activity-finish

I have an Application that contains an Activity with a Text Box and a button, and a Service that uses this Name entered in the Text Box by the user. Once I enter the name and Start the service (on button Click), I call finish() to destroy the Activity as shown in the code below :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_start);
    Log.e("onCreate", "Activity");

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startServiceBTN);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameTB);
            if (!hit) {
                hit = true;
                if (mEdit.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, BLEService.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Name", mEdit.getText().toString());
                    startService(intent);
                    StartActivity.this.finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please Enter a Valid Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

The problem which I face is, though I call the finish(), I could see the Applications Activity in the Recently Opened Apps Icon Tray (right most soft Button) that is next to the Back and Home Button on a Nexus 5.

On clicking the App in the Recently Opened Apps Tray, I get the App Back with empty Text Box. So I modified the above code with a check before setOnClickListener button click event, to ensure that on Return to the Activity, I pre-fill the Text Box with the user entered Text using the code snippet below.

```
if (hit) {
        EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameTB);
        mEdit.setText(BLEService.NameFromActivity);
        finish();
    }
```

Though the above snippet helps the Text box not to have a null value, the App Activity is again available in the Recent Apps Tray.

Here is my Problem. If I swipe close / swipe out the App in the Recent Apps Tray to clear it entirely, I start getting null as the value of Name in the service logs instead of the Name entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the following line in your `activity` tag in manifest file,

`android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

Setting it `true` will exclude this `Activity` from showing in recent tray. See below,

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

reference 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Worth to say that apps that are listed in the _recent apps list_ are not necessarily active in memory (check this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47652/do-applications-that-remain-in-recent-apps-list-take-up-resources).

Comment: Hi Spring Breaker, Thanks for the reply. Enabling excludeFromRecents, makes the log have only NULL value instead of NAME. I somehow need to preserve the Value (NAME) from the activity before destroying the Activity Object. I will check with SharedPrefs and update here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the text entered by the User, you may use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to save it.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("PREFERENCE_NAME", mEdit.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

Also in your `onCreate`, you could fetch that preference.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String defaultName = "John Doe";
String name = sharedPref.getString("PREFERENCE_NAME", defaultName);
mEdit.setText(name);
```